# BackboneJS : the model is fetched, but toJSON() and get() methods don't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Still learning Backbone, here is my code

```
const API_URL = 'http://api.brewerydb.com/v2';
const API_KEY = '********************************';

var Categories = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: API_URL + '/categories/?key=' + API_KEY
});

var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'categories',
    render: function()
    {
        var html = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < this.model.get('data').length; i++)
        {
            html += '<li>' + this.model.get('data')[i].name + '</li>';
        }

        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});

var categories = new Categories();
categories.fetch();

console.log(categories.toJSON());
```

My `console.log(categories.toJSON());` returns an empty object.

But when I do a `console.log(categories);`, the `attributes` property contains the data. And if I try a get on any of those attributes, it also doesn't work (`undefined`).

Comment: shouldn't you make `categories` a collection?

Comment: If I add a collection it doesn't change anything. I tried : `var BeersManager = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Categories });` and I get an empty array this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JavaScript executes asynchronously, your `console.log(categories.toJSON());` executes *before* `categories.fetch();` has finished execution.

This can be solved in a lot of different ways, but here are two common ones:

The first is using Backbone.Model's `fetch()` method, which accepts `success` and `error` callbacks:

```
categories.fetch({
  success: function() {
    console.log(categories.toJSON());        
  }
});
```

Here is an example of this (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oze92mw/1/)), which does the same thing (but pulls data from GitHub API instead as an example, since they have a public API).

The second way is a bit more complicated, but is a more common pattern in Backbone apps. This way involves adding an `initialize` function in your `CategoriesView`, and adding an event listener for Backbone's sync event. That event will fire a callback, after which you can execute your render function.

It also requires you to pass in a reference to your model when you call your new view constructor (see the very last line in the code below to see how this is done.)

This might seem a bit confusing, so I made another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rrnywfy/2/) which shows this in action, pulling data from the GitHub API again.

GitHub API example aside, your code would now look like this:

```
const API_URL = 'http://api.brewerydb.com/v2';
const API_KEY = '********************************';

var Categories = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: API_URL + '/categories/?key=' + API_KEY
});

var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'categories',
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.model.fetch();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    render: function()
    {
        // Your data will show up
        // in this case
        console.log(categories.toJSON());

        var html = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < this.model.get('data').length; i++)
        {
            html += '<li>' + this.model.get('data')[i].name + '</li>';
        }

        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});

var categories = new Categories();

// Create a new instance of the view,
// and pass in the model you just
// created
var categoriesView = new CategoriesView({ model: categories });
```

One weird thing you might notice is that in your view, you `listenTo` the `sync` event, *not* the `fetch` event. This is because as of Backbone 1.0,  `model.fetch()` actually triggers the `sync` event ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L568-L582)). I've always thought this was weird, so I thought I'd throw that in here :)

Comment: Amazingly explained, thank you very much ! This is interesting because that's the part I just learned : how to trigger and handle events between views and models :)